# PHP & DOM: How can I search through a single element using class names?

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

i'm trying to search through a series of HTML elements and extract the text in certain divs (based on the class name), however i seem to be unable to search through a single element, only all nodes.

```
<html>
<div class=parent>
    <div videoid=1></div>
    <div class=inner>Testing
        <div class=title>Test</div>
        <div class=date>Test</div>
        <div class=time>Test</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class=parent>
    <div videoid=2></div>
    <div class=inner>Testing
        <div class=title>Test</div>
        <div class=date>Test</div>
        <div class=time>Test</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class=parent>
    <div videoid=3></div>
    <div class=inner>Testing
        <div class=title>Test</div>
        <div class=date>Test</div>
        <div class=time>Test</div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
$url = new DOMDocument;
$url->loadHTMLFile("text.html");

$finder = new DomXPath($url);
$classname="parent";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
$count = 0;
foreach($nodes as $element) { //extracts each instance of the parent div into it's own element.

//within the parent div extract the value for the videoid attribute within the following child div belonging to the following attribute: videoid;

//within the parent div extract the text within the following child div belonging to the following class: title;

//within the parent div extract the text within the following child div belonging to the following class: date;

//within the parent div extract the text within the following child div belonging to the following class: time;
}
```

While there is only one instance of each of the child elements within each parent, they may be in any order in the parent div, and could be with their own children. Essentially i'm looking for some sort of recursive search I think?

Comment: can't you just search for `div[@class="parent"]`, your markup doesn't seem to match that. and just use the context node into getting the other child nodes under that

Comment: that's what i've done? That gets me each parent node as it's own element (within the for each loop), but It won't let me search those elements in the same manner. am I searching in the wrong way again? Should I not be using $finder->query?

Comment: yes @John you can search the remaning values (the chilren) under that loop (the found parent elements)

Comment: Well this is what i've put inside the for loop now: foreach($nodes as $element) {
$finder = new DomXPath($element);
$classname="date";
$dates = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
} But the error i'm getting is: "Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMXPath::__construct() must be an instance of DOMDocument, instance of DOMElement given"

Answer (score 1):

From the `parent` (elements) that you got, you can continue searching for those values that you needed. `->query(expression, context node)` has that second parameter wherein you can put the context node from where you need to search.

Rough example:

```
// for each found parent node
foreach($parents as $parent) {
    $id = $finder->query('./div[@class="id"]', $parent)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    // create another query                     ^ using the found parent as your context node
}
```

So in applying those:

```
$finder = new DomXPath($url);
$classname = "parent";
$parents = $finder->query("//div[@class='$classname']");
if($parents->length > 0) {
    foreach($parents as $parent) {
        $id = $finder->query('./div[@class="id"]', $parent)->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $title = $id = $finder->query('./div[@class="inner"]/div[@class="title"]', $parent)->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $date = $id = $finder->query('./div[@class="inner"]/div[@class="date"]', $parent)->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $time = $id = $finder->query('./div[@class="inner"]/div[@class="time"]', $parent)->item(0)->nodeValue;

        echo $id, '<br/>', $title, '<br/>', $date, '<br/>', $time, '<hr/>';
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1IRfVi)

Thats the case when you expect that structure to be like that always. You can just search inside the parent with a query and get the first one found, if the markup will be flexible:

```
foreach($parents as $parent) {
    $title = $finder->evaluate('string(.//*[@class="title"][1])', $parent);
    echo $title, '<br/>';
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tmwe9r)

Comment: I notice you've used item(0), now it's likely that the child elements will be within any order, and within any number of inner divs, not just directly under parent. How would I account for that? I think i'd need a recursive search that searches all the parent's children and their own children until it finds the element matching that class?

Comment: @JohnBergqvist yoiu'll need to change the query accordingly, on the edit

Comment: hmmm well it's not returning anything at all now :/ Is there any way for me to just view every single child & their children of each parent element? incase i've got the structure wrong or something?

Comment: @JohnBergqvist where is this html that you're testing anyway? i just simulated a sample jumbled element on each parent on the demo if you can see. do you mean iterate all elements inside each `parent`?

Comment: Yes. The code has so many extraneous elements, all in random orders so maybe it's too complex for it to parse through? The key thing is it needs to be able to search inside every element including it's children. So for example the ID div could be several divs inside another class within parent.

Comment: @JohnBergqvist yeah the `.//*` should work just fine inside that related `parent` it'll just get that children inside that for this example `title` http://codepad.viper-7.com/tmwe9r i just shuffled some of this, and added some depth inside the last `title`

Comment: OK well that's working for title & date & time now, however i've realised that the ID doesn't have it's own class, however the div is structured like so: <div videoid=12345></div> So how would I extract the number for the id value (i.e. finding the div that has an attribute of videoid?

Comment: @JohnBergqvist its hard to guess on this end how could i give an answer, could you reflect that explanation into the question body instead with the markup. anyway using `/@videoid` should work

Comment: @JohnBergqvist here's the version for the videoid stuff, you should have made it clearer from the beginning, your question keeps mutating, anyway here it is: http://codepad.viper-7.com/292yQ0 shouldn't that be a data attribute though?